# Nullpointer exception with wifi

Tags: android

I wrote a code which calculates the signal strength of a wifi access points and stores it in an array as shown below.

```
int signallevel = WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(result.level, 10);
signalStrength[i] = signallevel;
```

I am getting a null pointer exception in line 2.

Can any one please help me out. Thanks in advance

Comment: The problem will be in the `signalStrength[i]=` assignment, nothing to do with the statement before. Without seeing where that variable is defined and initialized it's not possible to say what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your variable `signalStrength` is not initialized. You could post a bit more code, too (just to verify the assumption).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a line like

```
int[] signalStrength = new int[SOME_SIZE]
```

If yes, are you sure that SOME_SIZE > i?